# Jruby version suitable for OpenJDK 8 (Zulu JDK)

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, azul-zulu, openjdk-8, azure-zulu

I am looking for an advisable version of JRuby that supports OpenJDK-8 (Zulu-JDK) to run on a Rails project.
Rails version- 4.0.13.

Answer (score 0):

All versions of JRuby since version 9.2.0.0 will run on JDK 8.  Since Zulu 8 is a build of OpenJDK 8 that means any appropriate JRuby version will run on Zulu 8.

Comment: Thank You for helping me out!

Comment: See my follow up question below. This statement does not appear to be true for an Apple M1 chip (ARM 64-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Follow up question (using answer section to get better code formatting then commenting on the answer above).

I'm trying to get JRuby > 9.2.0.0 running Zulu 8 for MacOS ARM 64-bit (M1 chip).

I did a reinstall of the JRuby versions after installing that JDK.

```
$ rvm list
   jruby-1.7.27 [ x86_64 ]
=> jruby-9.2.13.0 [ aarch64 ]
```

Check ruby version and try irb:

```
$ ruby -v
jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.302-b08 on 1.8.0_302-b08 +jit [darwin-aarch64]

$ irb
NotImplementedError: fstat unimplemented unsupported or native support failed to load; see https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Native-Libraries
  initialize at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1015
  open at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1156
  initialize at /Users/rrickerts/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.13.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/input-method.rb:141
  initialize at /Users/rrickerts/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.13.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb/context.rb:70
  initialize at /Users/rrickerts/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.13.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb.rb:410
       start at /Users/rrickerts/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.13.0/lib/ruby/stdlib/irb.rb:381
      <main> at /Users/rrickerts/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.13.0/bin/irb:13
```